# Retreiving files' meta-data via API lacks data on some deployents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using API call `/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/folder')/Files?$select=ListItemAllFields/ID,ListItemAllFields/FileRef,Properties&$expand=ListItemAllFields,Properties&$top=10&$skip=10`
to retrieve data about files in *folder*.

While on my test env (or on SharePoint cloud) I receive files' creation/modification times, and sizes (file-lengths), on my client those fields are missing from the xml.

What's the cause for this difference?
How can I fix this?

- My client runs *SharePoint 2013 Standard with SP1, patched to Jan 2018 CU.*

Client's API response:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://domain/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/some/file.ext')</id>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SP.File"/>
    <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/some/file.ext')" rel="edit"/>
    <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/some/file.ext')/ListItemAllFields" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ListItemAllFields" title="ListItemAllFields" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry">
        <m:inline>
            <entry m:etag="&quot;5&quot;">
                <id>Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/some/file.ext')/ListItemAllFields</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SP.Data.CDODocsItem"/>
                <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/some/file.ext')/ListItemAllFields" rel="edit"/>
                <title/>
                <updated>2018-08-27T09:58:06Z</updated>
                <author>
                    <name/>
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:Id>
                        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:ID>
                        <d:FileRef>/path/to/some/file.ext</d:FileRef>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </m:inline>
    </link>
    <title/>
    <updated>2018-08-27T09:58:06Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml"/>
</entry>
```

The response I receive from cloud/test lab:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://test.domain.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/aFile.doc')</id>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SP.File"/>
    <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/Scheduling%20Coordinator%20letter%2010-28-01%20path%2030.doc')" rel="edit"/>
    <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/Scheduling%20Coordinator%20letter%2010-28-01%20path%2030.doc')/ListItemAllFields" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ListItemAllFields" title="ListItemAllFields" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry">
        <m:inline>
            <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
                <id>4499279f-96a5-4ec4-9a5f-c905662b79d2</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SP.Data.Giltest2Item"/>
                <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/Scheduling%20Coordinator%20letter%2010-28-01%20path%2030.doc')/ListItemAllFields" rel="edit"/>
                <title/>
                <updated>2018-08-27T14:33:19Z</updated>
                <author>
                    <name/>
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
                        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID>
                        <d:FileRef>/giltest2/aFile.doc</d:FileRef>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </m:inline>
    </link>
    <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/Scheduling%20Coordinator%20letter%2010-28-01%20path%2030.doc')/Properties" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Properties" title="Properties" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry">
        <m:inline>
            <entry>
                <id>http://test.domain.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/aFile.doc')/Properties</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SP.PropertyValues"/>
                <link href="Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/giltest2/Scheduling%20Coordinator%20letter%2010-28-01%20path%2030.doc')/Properties" rel="edit"/>
                <title/>
                <updated>2018-08-27T14:33:19Z</updated>
                <author>
                    <name/>
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:vti_x005f_docstoreversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:vti_x005f_docstoreversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_metadatanextbsn>100</d:vti_x005f_metadatanextbsn>
                        <d:vti_x005f_nextbsn>150</d:vti_x005f_nextbsn>
                        <d:vti_x005f_replid>rid:{E98AEE2E-C7DD-4064-A659-7003C8042443}</d:vti_x005f_replid>
                        <d:vti_x005f_level m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:vti_x005f_level>
                        <d:OData__x005f_PID_x005f_GUID/>
                        <d:ContentTypeId>0x010100E4308556AF5E6244BAFA30F69D58345B</d:ContentTypeId>
                        <d:vti_x005f_setuppathversion m:type="Edm.Int32">16</d:vti_x005f_setuppathversion>
                        <d:OData__x005f_Comments/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_sourcecontrolversion>V1.0</d:vti_x005f_sourcecontrolversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_sourcecontrolcookie>fp_internal</d:vti_x005f_sourcecontrolcookie>
                        <d:Subject/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_filesize m:type="Edm.Int32">28160</d:vti_x005f_filesize>
                        <d:vti_x005f_modifiedby>SP01\administrator</d:vti_x005f_modifiedby>
                        <d:vti_x005f_title>Scheduling Coordinator:</d:vti_x005f_title>
                        <d:vti_x005f_streamschema m:type="Edm.Int32">66</d:vti_x005f_streamschema>
                        <d:vti_x005f_internalversion m:type="Edm.Int32">257</d:vti_x005f_internalversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_categories/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_parserversion>16.0.0.4351</d:vti_x005f_parserversion>
                        <d:Keywords/>
                        <d:OData__x005f_Author>MMcQuay-OSAT</d:OData__x005f_Author>
                        <d:vti_x005f_author>SP01\administrator</d:vti_x005f_author>
                        <d:vti_x005f_foldersubfolderitemcount m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:vti_x005f_foldersubfolderitemcount>
                        <d:vti_x005f_contentversionisdirty>false</d:vti_x005f_contentversionisdirty>
                        <d:vti_x005f_timecreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-08-14T06:42:19</d:vti_x005f_timecreated>
                        <d:vti_x005f_cachedtitle>Scheduling Coordinator:</d:vti_x005f_cachedtitle>
                        <d:vti_x005f_metainfoversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:vti_x005f_metainfoversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_cachedcustomprops>vti_approvallevel vti_categories Subject vti_assignedto Keywords _Status vti_title _Author _Category _PID_GUID _Comments</d:vti_x005f_cachedcustomprops>
                        <d:vti_x005f_contenttag>{E98AEE2E-C7DD-4064-A659-7003C8042443},1,1</d:vti_x005f_contenttag>
                        <d:vti_x005f_docstoretype m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:vti_x005f_docstoretype>
                        <d:vti_x005f_canmaybeedit>true</d:vti_x005f_canmaybeedit>
                        <d:vti_x005f_nextbsnallocated>150</d:vti_x005f_nextbsnallocated>
                        <d:OData__x005f_Status/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_folderitemcount m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:vti_x005f_folderitemcount>
                        <d:vti_x005f_approvallevel/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_rtag>rt:E98AEE2E-C7DD-4064-A659-7003C8042443@00000000001</d:vti_x005f_rtag>
                        <d:vti_x005f_parentid>{842AE712-3024-4DD4-A3A6-0FDF105761BF}</d:vti_x005f_parentid>
                        <d:OData__x005f_Category/>
                        <d:vti_x005f_candeleteversion>true</d:vti_x005f_candeleteversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_timelastmodified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-08-14T06:42:19</d:vti_x005f_timelastmodified>
                        <d:vti_x005f_contentversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:vti_x005f_contentversion>
                        <d:vti_x005f_etag>&quot;{E98AEE2E-C7DD-4064-A659-7003C8042443},1&quot;</d:vti_x005f_etag>
                        <d:vti_x005f_timelastwritten m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-08-14T06:42:19</d:vti_x005f_timelastwritten>
                        <d:vti_x005f_assignedto/>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </m:inline>
    </link>
    <title/>
    <updated>2018-08-27T14:33:19Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml"/>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the REST API below to retrieve file itemId, file path, file size, file created time and last modified time. Both works in SharePoint 2013 on-premise and SharePoint Online.

**`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/path/to/folder')/Files?$select=ListItemAllFields/Id,ListItemAllFields/FileRef,Length,TimeCreated,TimeLastModified&$expand=ListItemAllFields&$top=10`**

Comment: Unfortunately, that produced "empty" data answer: 

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://52.36.112.60:54321/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
 <id>8eb97b13-49c7-4fc6-a979-384b7f8b6caf</id>
 <title/>
 <updated>2018-08-28T08:39:09Z</updated>
 <author>
  <name/>
 </author>
</feed>`

Comment: remove &$skip=10 in the rest api

Comment: Didn't do the trick :-( removed top&skip parameters.
Should this call work the same on sp-online? 2016?

Comment: Remove $skip=10, it works in my SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013 on-premise test environment.